# Summing Selected Numbers in a Matrix

Tags: c#, for-loop, matrix, data-structures

I am trying to sum some elements of a matrix with for loop. I successed to sum all elements of matrix but I could not sum the selected ones. Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace debugginglab
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] matrix = { { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }, 
                              { 1, 3, 4, 6, 5 }, 
                              { 6, 3, 2, 1, 0 }, 
                              { 2, 5, 7, 11,20,}, 
                              { 13,17,19,23,25} };
            int sum = summing(matrix);
            Console.WriteLine(toplam);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static int summing(int[,] m)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < m.GetLength(0); ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < m.GetLength(1); ++j)
                    toplam += m[i, j];
            return sum;
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
     
    }
}
```

Now my problem: For example I want to select 3,3,5 from second column sum them find the 11 result. How can I pick and sum them with **for loop**? Thanks.

Comment: What's `toplam`? Seems like you should do `sum += m[i, j];`

Comment: If you're selecting the values 3,3,5, then sum the selection. But to write this code, you need to know the **why**, rather than the values. That is, you need to describe the _criteria_ used for making that selection. Then you can translate that criteria into a code. And when I say "criteria", I don't mean just `(1,1), (1,2), (1,3)`. I mean: _why those positions_, and not different positions? Where does that come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here You have a ***basic*** version of program using `for` loops to sum selected part of given matrix.
Mind that it does not provide You with any type of overflow / type / etc safety - this is up to You.

```
using System;       

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] matrix = { { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }, 
                         { 1, 3, 4, 6, 5 }, 
                         { 6, 3, 2, 1, 0 }, 
                         { 2, 5, 7, 11,20,}, 
                         { 13,17,19,23,25} };

        Console.WriteLine("Start column (from 0)");
        var fromColumn = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("End column (from 0)");
        var toColumn = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Start row (from 0)");
        var fromRow = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("end row (from 0)");
        var toRow = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int sum = summing(matrix, fromColumn, toColumn, fromRow, toRow);
        Console.WriteLine("Sum is: " + sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    static int summing(int[,] m, int fromColumn, int toColumn, int fromRow, int toRow)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++)
        {
            for(int j = fromColumn; j <= toColumn; j++)
            {
                sum+= m[i,j];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

For example mentioned in Your post (sum of 3, 3, 1), You would need to input start col as 1, end col as 1, start row as 1, end row as 3.